# Must Complete Steps for new Windows Server 2008 Deployment?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I just launched my first server with go-grid (cloud).  Its a 2GB instance running Windows Server 2008 (64-bit) version.  I've installed the IIS components that I'll need along with SQL Express 2008 for the websites that I'll be hosting on there.

I'm a developer by trade and server hardening/security are completely foreign to me.  What are the things that I should do next to improve the security on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got the components that you need for the server's intended purpose installed, configured, and tested, run the Security Configuration Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider using the [Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923.aspx). I would use it as a guide, as opposed to gospel, to help check on some of your configurations. It's not perfect, but a nice tool to have.